# While loop in C prints the same line more than once

Tags: c, while-loop, char, getchar

```
char ch;
int nr=0;

printf("\n: "); 
ch = getchar();

while(ch != 'q' && ch != 'Q'){
    ch = tolower(ch);
    if(ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'u')
        nr++;
    
    printf("something");
    ch = getchar();
}
    
printf("vocale: %d", nr);
```

its supposed to count the number of vowels until the user presses q or Q. it's such a silly program and yet i cant get past it.

Comment: Please include a [mre] in your question.

Comment: Aside: what crime did `y` commit?

Comment: Of course it prints `"something"` every time. You've told it to.

Comment: It likely prints them all at once because your IO is buffered and you haven't printed a newline.

Comment: Your 2nd `getchar()` reads the `'\n'` left in `stdin` by the user pressing **Enter** following the first input.

Comment: So close to doing `while (tolower(ch) == 'q')` or `char ch = tolower(getchar())`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError `'y'` is not a proper vowel in the English language. (though I've seen others mistakenly include it -- must be like that "New Math" stuff)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I see - learn something every day.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - no worries, language issues stand out like seeing `gets()` in code `:)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is, that the input only gets flushed to your program whenever the user presses enter. Another reason why it seems not to work is, because you don't have a newline at the end of you output (`printf("vocale: %d", nr);` ), which causes the output not to be flushed to the terminal when the program ends. Fix this and your program works, but maybe not as you expect it to, because you still have to press enter. It will still only count to the first 'q' found.

```
int main() {
    char ch;
    int nr = 0;
    printf(": "); 
    while(tolower(ch = getchar()) != 'q'){
        ch = tolower(ch);
        if(ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'u')
            nr++;
    }
    printf("vocale: %d\n", nr);
}
```

The program:

```
: aeu q oi (here I pressed enter)
vocale: 3
```

Comment: Just a note, the `printf("vocale: %d", nr);` after the close of the loop lacking a `'\n'` has nothing to do with streams not getting flushed (at that location). Streams are flushed and closed at program exit.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `getchar`

```
ch = getchar();
```

that also reads white space characters use `scanf` like

```
scanf( " %c", &ch );
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters.

For example

```
while ( scanf( " %c", &ch ) == 1 && ch != 'q' && ch != 'Q'){
```

Also it will be more safer to write

```
ch = tolower( ( unsigned char )ch );
```